# Packaging several browser Plugins for distribution?

Tags: plugins, package, exe

I am trying to package a set of plugins in order to distribute them out to different users. I do not know how to do this.

I know plugins are essentially software with their own .exe you have to run in order to get installed onto your computer for your browser to detect them, but I do not know how to package several EXE's into one for simple distribution.

Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

ex: I want to be able to have one program to install Adobe Flash, Microsoft Silverlight, Adobe Acrobat, etc.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I am just running each individual executable for each plugin with system("program.exe") and calling those. I would like a much better solution to this instead, without having the user having to go through each installation themselves.